# How can I get nodemailer to work with heroku?

Tags: heroku, nodemailer

I am using nodemailer and gmail on my portfolio site which is used to send messages directly to my email. This works on my local server (localhost:3000) but doesn't work when I deploy it to heroku. I did however get a message from gmail 'someone has accessed your account' after I deployed with heroku incase that's relevant.

Here is my app.js:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    secure: false,
    port: 25,
    auth:{
        user: 'myownemail@gmail.com',
        pass: '**************'
    }
})

let mailOptions = {
    from: '"Portfolio Message" <myotheremail@gmail.com> ',
    to: 'myownemail@gmail.com',
    subject: '',
    text: '',
    html: ''
}

app.post('/message/new',function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify({ status: "OK" }));
    res.end();
    mailOptions['subject'] = 'new portfolio message from ' + req.body.name ;
    mailOptions['text'] = req.body.message + " \n      " + " phone number or email : " + req.body.phone_or_email;

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,(error,info)=>{
        error?console.log('error',error):console.log('success');
    });

})
```

I've abstracted away some of my other code in app.js that I think is irrelevant to this question. Can anyone tell me how to get this to work with heroku?

Answer (score 0):

You have to Enable less secure apps from google.

I had same issue, but I solved this by going to the following url (while connected to google with the account I want to send mail from):

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

There I enabled less secure apps.

And your are done!

Comment: Works for localhost but not heroku deployment

Comment: You should check if the port is open on Heroku. Google mail SMTP use 465 port. So check if it is open on heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How exactly do I check?

Comment: Did you check by changing your port value to 465 in the code? You have `port: 25,` but change it to `port: 465,` and then give it a try. If it does not work then comment back here.

Comment: I'm getting an error on heroku `invalid login` in my heroku logs. I've already set up less secure apps and everything